# Magento: where are these methods

Tags: php, oop, magento, inheritance

I am making simple plugin for magento and I don't know where these method are,for example:

```
class Magentostudy_News_Block_adminhtml_News_Grid extends
    Mage_adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(); //I know that here is called super class constructor, but i don't know sure where $this->setId is called?
        $this->setId('news_list_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersIn
    }
}
```

Comment: try searching in doc of magento.

http://doc-magento.com/nav.html?index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can track this down by following the hierarchy of Magento

```
 Magentostudy_News_Block_adminhtml_News_Grid 
 extends
 Mage_adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid which 
 extends  
 Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget
```

The function setId is defined around line 36 of

/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget.php

This is defined as getId() with my explanation below:

Magento as many other systems use magic setters and getters.   The function setId is a magic Method of getId. In the function"getId()" it accepts a parameter of an "id" so if you use "setId($id) it will setId to the $id you pass it.

Comment: Hi Rob Thank you for helping me, but I show only getId() method here!

Comment: If you have a more specific example of what you are looking to accomplish I will be glad to help.

Comment: On the extends part you are right, but this is kinda unclear `In the function"getId()" it accepts a parameter of an "id" so if you use "setId($id) it will setId to the $id you pass it.`
The function sets a key in a protected $_data array. So `$this->setKeyBlaBla($value)` it's short for `$this->setData('key_bla_bla', $value);` 
The function setId depending on the object your are calling it, will set the key `id` or another specified id field, for example `entity_id` for most of Magento's collections.

Comment: I sometimes try to not go too far off with my answers, in this context I'm really unsure what he/she is looking to accomplish. However, in more detail then my response you are 100% correct Emi